# How to handle user click the "delete button " in setEditing in TableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I added a editButton on the table like this:

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

and, having a setEditing method:

```
- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.watchListDetailTableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if (editing) {
            // you might disable other widgets here... (optional)
    } else {
            // re-enable disabled widgets (optional)
    }
}
```

after I click the edit, I can have a cross and delete button, which method should I do to handle the delete button click? thank you.

Answer (score 7):

This should be it:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

[More Info Here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:)

> When users tap the insertion (green
>   plus) control or Delete button
>   associated with a UITableViewCell 
>   object in the table view, the table
>   view sends this message to the data
>   source, asking it to commit the
>   change. (If the user taps the deletion
>   (red minus) control, the table view
>   then displays the Delete button to get
>   confirmation.) The data source commits
>   the insertion or deletion by invoking
>   the UITableView methods
>   insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
>   or
>   deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:,
>   as appropriate.